# Prove by induction $n^2 \leq n!$ for $n\geq 4$.

Tags: proof-writing, induction

I managed to get $P(4):4^2 = 16 \geq 24 = 4!$

But then assuming $n^2 \geq n!, \forall n\geq4\in\mathbb{Z}$, I need to prove $(n+1)^2 \geq (n+1)!$

I tried $n^2+2n+1\geq n!\cdot (n+1)$, but I got stuck.

Any thoughts on how to continue?

Comment: In your title the inequality goes one way and in your question it goes the other. One of them will be much easier to prove. Start by verifying the direction of inequality. Almost always the assumption we make in the second step is used in the proof of the inductive step, see if you can use the assumption.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:
$$n!>n^2$$
$$(n+1)!= (n+1)\cdot n! > (n+1)\cdot n^2 > (n+1)^2$$

Comment: This answer is better than mine :)

Comment: A little more justification for the final inequality is required, because it is valid if and only if $$n \in \left( -1, \tfrac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2} \right) \cup \left( \tfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}, \infty \right),$$ of which $n \ge 4$ is a proper subset; but it is clearly not true for general $n$--thus the need for a little more detail.

Comment: If it was a full answer I would mention that $n\geq 4$, but I figured a hint would suffice

Comment: @jameselmore Agreed ^_^

Comment: It took me a little bit of cranking, but the penny finally dropped.  Thanks to all of you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

To make things easier, prove that $$n+1 \leqslant n!$$ for $n\geqslant 4$. (This is straightforward.)

Recall that $(n+1)! = (n+1)n!$. So given that $n^2 \leqslant n!$, we have

$$(n+1)! = (n+1)n! \geqslant (n+1)(n+1) = (n+1)^2.  $$

Comment: Thanks.  That will do nicely, and I learned something.  Win-win for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the meat of the inductive proof (i.e., the inductive step):
\begin{align}
(k+1)! &= (k+1)\cdot k!\tag{by definition}\\[0.5em]
&\geq (k+1)\cdot k^2\tag{by inductive hypothesis}\\[0.5em]
&= k^3+k^2\tag{expand}\\[0.5em]
&\geq k^2+2k+1\tag{since $k\geq 4$}\\[0.5em]
&= (k+1)^2.\tag{factor}
\end{align}
That is really what you need to show for the inductive step.

**Note:** It may be more interesting to show that $2^n<n!$ for $n\geq 4$. [Just a thought]